# Querying MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am working on someone else program. I have 2 tables Products and Seller. These tables are connected and the connection is made in the Seller table. I want to display the Product name from the Products table and also display the Seller who has made the product entry.

This is how I display the product table:

```
public function getProductName($product_id,$language_id) {
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description WHERE
                           product_id = '".(int)$product_id."' 
                           AND language_id = '".(int)$language_id."'");
    if($query->row AND $query->row['name'] != '') { 
     return $query->row['name'];
   } else { 
       return '-';
    }
}
```

The Seller table has fields `seller_name`, `seller_id`, `sproduct_id`. How can I pull the associated seller name for each product?

Comment: Do you want all product_names or just for the respective product_id?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! All the product names in the database and display the seller who made that entry. The 'sproduct_id' associates the product entered by the seller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to join the two tables together on the common `product_id` key. Here's the resultant Sql you'll want. Also, if product_id and language_id are integers in the database (as they seem to be in PHP) that you can drop the '':

```
"SELECT pd.name, s.seller_name
 FROM " . DB_PREFIX . ".product_description pd 
    INNER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . ".Seller s on pd.product_id = s.sproduct_id
 WHERE 
     product_id = ".(int)$product_id."
     AND language_id = ".(int)$language_id.";";
```

Comment: Hi Sutart... I appreciate your reply, I am going to try this and let you know... thank you!

Comment: Yes - we are joining `product_description.product_id` to `Seller.s.sproduct_id` - I've just aliased the two tables.

Comment: Yes, I realized that on second reading... I will try it now... thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Using your code:

```
public function getProductName($product_id, $language_id)
{

    $strSQL = "SELECT p.name, s.seller_name FROM " . DB_PREFIX .
              "product_description p INNER JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . 
              "Seller s ON p.product_id = s.sproduct_id WHERE product_id = '" .
              intval($product_id) . "' AND language_id = '" .
              intval($language_id) . "'";

    $query = $this->db->query($strSQL);
    if($query->row AND $query->row['name'] != '') { 
        return $query->row['name'];
    } else { 
        return '-';
    }
}
```

If product_id and language_id are integer values you don't need to enclosed them in ''. Also remember to add error checking to make sure that $product_id and $language_id have valid values for your query. More info on [SQL joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).